# Grunt/npm compiled CSS differs between computers

Tags: gruntjs, npm

I've been using grunt/npm for a few months now, but I'm having 2 small issues (that I've noticed): one on computer the CSS includes the bang of CSS comments while on the other computer it does for the same project/repo and on one the font-family declaration doesn't have spaces while on the other it does.

For example, on computer will do the following:

```
 /* normalize.css v3.0.0 | MIT License | git.io/normalize */
 font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif
```

While the other computer will do:

```
 /*! normalize.css v3.0.0 | MIT License | git.io/normalize */
 font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif
```

I'm using the grunt tasks: uglify, compass, autoprefixer, and watch. My full config is here: https://github.com/xmmedia/xm_template/blob/kohana_v3.3/master/Gruntfile.js

Any ideas what I need to change to make them consistent?

Comment: Is there a difference in operating systems between the two machines?

Comment: They are both OSX 10.9.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue!...well I'm not sure what the issue was, but they now generate the same results.

I basically ran `\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby`, `gem update`, `sudo gem update` and which seems to have updated everything such that both have all the same versions now.

Answer (score 1):

Compass is the only gem in that collection, so your systems probably had a different compass versions installed.

Answer (score 0):

If your Gruntfile.js and package.json are the same on both machines look at your installed npm modules for differences in version. One way to do that is to install `npm install -g npm-check-updates` and run it (`npm-check-updates`) in the root directory of the project on each machine.

Comment: I tried this, but unfortunately it didn't make a difference. I also ran npm install, npm update and npm update -g but that didn't help either.